# show that $\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)\sin(\theta_3-\theta_4)+\dots+=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

By using substitution of the form $x=\cos2\theta+i \sin2\theta$  in the identity

> $(x_1-x_2)(x_3-x_4)+(x_2-x_3)(x_1-x_4)+(x_3-x_1)(x_2-x_4)=0$

show that $\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)\sin(\theta_3-\theta_4)+\dots+=0$

I have tried expanding the equation and I end up with $x_1=x_2$ and I am not sure how it will help me.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
x_1-x_2 &= (\cos 2\theta_1 - \cos 2\theta_2) +  i(\sin 2\theta_1 - \sin 2\theta_2) \\
&=-2\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2) +2i \cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2) \\
&=2i\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)(\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)+i\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2))
\end{align*}
Similarly,
\begin{align*}
x_3-x_4 &=2i\sin(\theta_3-\theta_4)(\cos(\theta_3+\theta_3)+i\sin(\theta_3+\theta_4))
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
(x_1-x_2)(x_3-x_4) &= -4\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)\sin(\theta_3-\theta_4)(\cos(\theta_1+\cdots +\theta_4)+ i\sin(\theta_1+\cdots +\theta_4))
\end{align*}
Writing similarly the second and third terms and adding, we obtain the desired result.